# How can I set custom template for item in list and than use it inside `v-for` loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index>
  <div v-if="item.Component">
    <item.Component :value="item.value" />
  </div>
  <div v-else>{{ item.value }}</div>
</li>
```

But anyway I don't like at all this solution. The idea of defining `Component` key for an item in items list is hard to maintain since at least it is hard to write it in template-style way (usually we are talking about too long HTML inside). Also I don't like to wrap `item.Component` inside `div`.

```
data() {
  return {
    list: [{
      value: 'abc',
      Component: {
        props: ['value'],
        template: `123 {{ value }} 312`
      }
    }]
  };
}
```

Does anyone know the best-practice solution for this and where Vue describes such case in their docs?

Comment: Have you tried implementing it with `slots`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vue's [`<component/>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html?) tag to dynamically set your component in your list.

```html
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index>
  <component v-if="item.Component" :is="item.Component" :value="item.value"></component>
  <div v-else>{{ item.value }}</div>
</li>

<script>
  ...,
  data: () => ({
    list: [{
      value: 'abc',
      Component: {
        props: ['value'],
        template: `<div>123 {{ value }} 312</div>` // must be enclosed in a element.
      }
    }]
  })
</script>
```

You can also import a component too so you can create a new file and put your templates and scripts there.

*Parent.vue*

```html
<script>
import SomeComponent from "@/components/SomeComponent.vue";  //import your component here.

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        {
          value: "abc",
          Component: SomeComponent  // define your imported component here.
        },
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

*SomeComponent.vue*

```html
<template>
  <div>123 {{ value }} 312</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "SomeComponent",
  props: ["value"]
};
</script>
```

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leaf-g453k?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).